# Arcpy multiple ring buffer error 000210: Cannot create output

Tags: python-2.7, arcpy

I have problem using MultipleRingBuffer_analysis from arcpy library. Script that was previously working (14 days ago) and i havent touched it now suddenly stopped working and started returning this error message:

MultipleRingBuffer   C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.2\arcpy\arcpy\analysis.py   854
ExecuteError: ERROR 000210: Cannot create output C:\Users\Mates\AppData\Local\Temp\scratch.gdb\union.shp.shp
ERROR 000354: The name contains invalid characters
Failed to execute (Union).

I just found out that if I import this script directly into arcmap toolbox it works without problems. It only fails when running from interpreter (I am using pyscripter)

Failed to execute (MultipleRingBuffer).

```
import arcpy
import csv
import sys
import os


from arcpy import env
env.workspace = "E:\\BAKALARKA\\databases\\test.gdb"
input_table = "C:\\temp\\csvTable.csv"
output = "E:\\BAKALARKA\\databases\\test.gdb\\test1"
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput=True


number_of_buffers = 4
spacing = 1000
distance = spacing*number_of_buffers
number_of_sectors = 8
x_field = 0
y_field = 0
angle = 360/number_of_sectors
buffers = []

for x in range(1,number_of_buffers+1):
    x = x*spacing
    buffers.append(x)

print buffers

##print buffers
path = "C:\\temp\\csvTable.csv"

def table():
    try:
        file = open(path,"wt")
        writer = csv.writer(file)
        writer.writerow(("x","y","bearing","distance"))
        for i in range (number_of_sectors):
            writer.writerow((int(x_field),int(y_field),int(angle*i),int(spacing*(i+1))))

        file.close()


    except:
        print "Something went wrong :("
table()
##
##
##
arcpy.BearingDistanceToLine_management(input_table,"E:\\BAKALARKA\\databases\\test.gdb\\lines","x","y","distance","METERS","bearing","DEGREES")
arcpy.MultipleRingBuffer_analysis("E:\\BAKALARKA\\databases\\test.gdb\\origin_point","E:\\BAKALARKA\\databases\\test.gdb\\buffers_output",buffers,"meters")
arcpy.FeatureToLine_management("E:\\BAKALARKA\\databases\\test.gdb\\buffers_output","E:\\BAKALARKA\\databases\\test.gdb\\buffers_line")
arcpy.FeatureToPolygon_management(["lines","buffers_line"],"E:\\BAKALARKA\\databases\\test.gdb\\sectors")
```

Comment: The error message is very unusual, as you are not inputting any shapefiles--yet the error message indicates a bad extension (`.shp.shp`) for a union operation. Any ideas why there is reference to shapefiles when you are using FGDB feature classes?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your scratch workspace is not recognized as a geodatabase, but rather as a folder. This may mean that this geodatabase is corrupt (e.g. because it misses a file called 'gdb'). The Multiple Ring Buffer tool will write temporary files such as the union file mentioned in the error as either shp or gdb data. If it thiks the scratch is a folder, it will write shp files.

Try setting your scratch folder to another geodatabase of which you are certain it works (`arcpy.env.scratchWorkspace = 'c:/example.gdb'`).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It appears that your scratch gdb is corrupted. All I did was go to my temp folder where the scratch gdb is, delete it and run the script. Worked great.